# laravel .htaccess in root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I am following this [article](https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess).

I am using `laravel 5.6`.

I moved `.htaccess` file from `public` to `root` and renamed `server.php` to `index.php`.

.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

But `css` and `js` files are not loaded.

Comment: You will need to start debugging. What us shown as a request result in your browsers network console and what does your http server's error log file reveal?

Comment: how do you load css or js files ??

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to do that , you only need to create `.htaccess` file in root directory and put that in it :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

after that you can keep your `css , js` files in public folder put you can call them directrly without `public`

Answer (score 0):

since your app is now getting served from your app root instead of app/public, the app is looking css and js files in the root of your app.

You can easily fix this issue, by adding `{{ asset('public') }}` in front of your css and js files.

for example

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public') }}/css/style.min.css"/>
<script src="{{ asset('public') }}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```